# deal with IDs in components when using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I recently refactored my state in redux to match the guideline.

```
foo: {
  allIds: [1],
  byId: {
    1: {
      properties: [2, 3]
    }
  }
}
properties: {
  allIds: [2, 3],
  byId: {
    2: {text: 'property 2'},
    3: {text: 'property 3'}
  }
}
```

I have been able to do more generic actions.
But now there's id everywhere, I don't know really how to deal with them.

I've `<Foo />` component and `<Propertie />`. When my state was a tree:

```
foo: {
  properties: [{text: 'property 1'}, {text: 'property 2'}]
}
```

I was able to do (in Foo)

```
render() {
  const {properties} = this.props;

  return properties.map(property => <Property entity={property} />) 
}
```

Now, this is more complicated because property has become a list of ids.

My first thought is to do a container component for property:

`PropertyContainer.js`

```
const getEntity = id => state.properties.byId[id];

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  entity: getEntity(ownProps.id)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Property)
```

And now, I would able to do (in foo)

```
render() {
  const {properties} = this.props;

  return properties.map(property => <PropertyContainer id={property} />) 
}
```

The good part if that it doesn't change my `<Property>` component at all and the component are more separated. The bad part is I need to create more container component that are related to the store. The parent component (like foo) and also highly related to the store because it has ids.

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: It was what Dan Abramov did here: https://github.com/mweststrate/redux-todomvc/pull/1/files

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but it what I do for now:

in foo:

```
render() {
  const {properties} = this.props;
  return properties.map(property => <PropertyContainer property={property} />
}
```

That way, I hide the fact I use ids internally.

And in the `PropertyContainer` I just convert the id to the real entity.

```
const getPropertySelector = (state, id) => state.properties.byId[id];

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {property: id} = ownProps;

  return {
    ...getPropertySelector(id)
  };
};
```